# Merge two single link lists in c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am writing a function that takes two list structures, each list struct contains two pointers, one to the first node in a list and the other to the last in the list.
I am getting a segmentation fault at the if line on the if line.
Here is my function:

```
extern void lst_merge_sorted(LIST *a, LIST *b);
void lst_merge_sorted(LIST *a, LIST *b){
NODE *aCurr,*bCurr,*aTemp,*bTemp;
aCurr = a->front;
bCurr = b->front;
aTemp = a->front;
bTemp = b->front;
int aLength = 2, bLength = 2;
while(aCurr->next != NULL){
    aLength++;
    aCurr = aCurr->next;
    }
while(bCurr->next != NULL){
    bLength++;
    bCurr = bCurr->next;
    }
int i,j;
for (i = 0; i < aLength; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < bLength; j++){
        if (bTemp->val < aTemp->val){
            bTemp->next = aTemp->next;
            aTemp->next = bTemp;
            }
        bTemp = bTemp->next;
        }
    aTemp = aTemp->next;
    }
}
```

and my List Struct/Node Struct:

```
typedef struct node {
    ElemType val;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;


struct list_struct {
    NODE *front;
    NODE *back;
};
```

Does anybody have any idea why I am getting a seg fault?
EDIT
ElemType declaration is

```
Typedef int ElemType
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < aLength; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < bLength; j++){` IMO it makes no sense to first count the lists.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't make sense. Any idea on the seg fault though? @wildplasser

Comment: Please take a look at the older topics to the right `-->>` . Stuff like this can be handled quite elegantly in 10 lines of code. Without counting.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at that nested loop.  You probably really did not want to go through list b aLength * bLength times.